# HTML5 - SVG elements acting differently on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

My goal is to align a 'div' below a 'textarea' inside a 'svg' and 'g' element. On Firefox it works, on Chrome it does not.

Basically i apply a transform at the 'g' element and that element goes correctly to the position i wanted. However, having nested elements with the "class" property are incorrectly positioned, and what i mean is: having a single 'i' element without childs works fine, having a 'span' does not.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit; position: fixed;" version="1.1" >
 <g id="g1" transform="translate(130,30) ">
  <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" overflow="visible" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
            <textarea style="background: white; color: black; border-radius:6px;border-style: solid; border-width: 3px;  width: 140px; font-size: 12px; resize: none; height: 50px">test</textarea>

            <div style="margin-top: -5px;height: 33px;">
                    <a href=""> 
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                       
                        <span  class="fa-stack" title="Insert section" >
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
  </foreignObject>
 </g>
</svg>
```

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display: inline; width: inherit; min-width: inherit; max-width: inherit; height: inherit; min-height: inherit; max-height: inherit; position: fixed;" version="1.1" >
    <g id="g1" transform="translate(130,30) ">
        <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="150" height="150" overflow="visible" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
            <textarea style="background: white; color: black; border-radius:6px;border-style: solid; border-width: 3px;  width: 140px; font-size: 12px; resize: none; height: 50px">test</textarea>

            <div style="margin-top: -5px;height: 33px;">
                    <a href=""> 
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>

                        <span  class="fa-stack" title="Insert section" >
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Run the fiddle on both browsers to see the problem i referred: 
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24vxL2vv/)

Here are the images:

Firefox: [image: Fiddle result Firefox]
Chrome: [image: Fiddle result Chrome]

Thank you in advance o7

**EDIT1:**

> Most likely a bug in chrome. You should open an issue on their bug-tracker. (when you do inspect the element, the bbox is drawn at the correct position, but the element itself is rendered completely off);

regarding Kaiido aswer, it really seems a issue with Chrome since there are multiple instances relating svg and chrome. another fun-fact is that the icon is rendered based on the height of the textarea, more precisely, if i put 200px as the textarea height, the icon would be further down aswell like and invisible textare was above.

Comment: Why do you create an svg to put only html content inside it?

Comment: Franz Deschler, not sure if i understood correctly but this code is just a snippet from the whole project and its the one that causes me trouble. in regards of svg, i use Paths and it also allows me to have zoom, move content (positions) and others.

Comment: I understand. I thought you would just put html in the svg.

Comment: Most likely a bug in chrome. You should open an issue on their bug-tracker. (when you do inspect the element, the bbox is drawn at the correct position, but the element itself is rendered completely off);

Comment: Kaiido, I've read multiple instances of problems about svg and chrome, and it seems that there is a very similar bug already posted on their bug-tracker since 2015 and they keep handling it as low importance for some reason even tho is has thousands of coments and stuff :/ PS: made an edit and refered what you said + some insight of the icon position

Answer (score -6):

try to remove this part from the code.

[image: Check this image to see the part that needs to be deleted]

Comment: what? besides, this is comment not an answer

Comment: Perhaps you forgot someting in your comment :P

Comment: Can't do that, i need the svg since is has more stuff besides this problem i posted here.

Comment: Plese check the image

Comment: @HélderF. try to delete this <g id="g1" transform="translate(130,30) ">

Comment: Can't do that aswell, i need that <g> for the repeater since that g is the whole element of the textarea+buttons that i showed:/